# Saving 2 textbox array in database PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach

I have 2 textbox array,
questions & correct answer...

the problem is , i cannot save it to the the database
questions should be saved to "test" field in database
and correct answer should be saved to "test2" field...

code for the textbox

```
echo "<label for='textfield[]' align='left'> Question </label>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<input type='text'  name='textfield[]'>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<label for='textfield2[]' align='left'> Correct Answer </label>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<input type='text'  name='textfield2[]'>";
echo "<br/>";
```

code for inserting values in database

```
$sql = array();
foreach($_POST['textfield'] as $textfield){
foreach($_POST['textfield2'] as $textfield2){
$sql[] = "INSERT INTO practice (test,test2) VALUES ('{$textfield}','{$textfield2}')";
}
}
foreach($sql as $query){
mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to have two text entries and insert these two text entries into a database? Just to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert like this,

```
<?php    
$post_count = count($_POST['textfield']);
$post1 = array();
$post2 = array();
$post1 = $_POST['textfield'];
$post2 = $_POST['textfield2'];
for ($i = 0; $i <= $post_count; $i++) {
    $sql[] = "INSERT INTO practice (test,test2) VALUES ('".$post1[$i]."','".$post2[$i]."')";
}
foreach ($sql as $query) {
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not forget to quote the data with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Also, there's no need for an intermediate array, only use it if you're going to submit all queries in one operation.